# Custom editor in QAbstractTableModel

Tags: model-view-controller, qt, qabstracttablemodel

Does anyone have an example of using a QWidget as an editor in a QAbstractTableModel?
I have a column which when edited should create a QCombobox with the list of choices.

The docs seem to suggest I need to write a QAbstractItemDelegate and a custom paint function but that seems overkill to simply pop-up a standard QCombobox in Qt::EditRole.

Note - the combo box contents are the same for every row and it only needs to be shown when somebody clicks in the cell.

I know this should be simple but I can't get it to work. It's easy for a QTableWidget based table - but I need it for a very large data table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The docs seem to suggest I need to write a QAbstractItemDelegate and a custom paint function but that seems overkill to simply pop-up a standard QCombobox in Qt::EditRole.

You don't need to go that far.  One way is to subclass `QStyledItemDelegate` and then override [`createEditor()`](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qstyleditemdelegate.html#createEditor) so that it returns your prepopulated combo box.  Its `setEditorData` and `setModelData` functions will probably already suffice if you`re using basic Qt value types.

If you need something more generic that works across many different models, you can create a [`QItemEditorFactory`](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qitemeditorfactory.html) that associates your editor with the correct type.  This also works well with custom types.

When indicated by your view's [`EditTrigger`](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qabstractitemview.html#EditTrigger-enum), your view will get the delegate specific to the cell on which the edit is being invoked and call `delegate->createEditor(...)` which can then size the combo box according to the `options` parameter as well as set the current entry to the value specified by the model, although most of this should be handled by the `QStyledItemDelegate`.  Thus, you won't have to worry about the `Qt::EditRole` directly as the view will handle that.

Comment: Thanks that helped - how do I actually hook the delegate into the Qt::Editrole in QAbstractTableModel?

Comment: Thats what I though but it wasn't working. I found the spinbox example - once you had given me the "QStyledItemDelegate" thank you

Answer (score 1):

Did you try and have a look at the following example from Qt :

[Spin Box Delegate Example](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6//itemviews-spinboxdelegate.html)

Maybe it will give you a much clearer view on the subject !

Hope it helps a bit !

Comment: Thanks - found it just after I posted the comment!